# Matrix equations, reversible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A reversible matrix is ​​given $A \in R_{3\times 3}$  and matrix $B$ formed from $A$ as a result of the operations

1. $r_1-2r_3$,
2. $r_2+r_3$,
3. $2 \cdot r_2$,

where $r_i$ is the $i$-th row of the matrix. Find matrix $X$ satisfying the equation $X \cdot A=B$

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HINT

row operations correspond to left matrix multiplication

EG try starting with I 3-by-3 and exchange 2 row now multiply another matrix 3-by-3 on the left with the new I*